# What does a non-negative drug test mean

Tags: hiring-process

Took 3 home test and all came back negative. Then I took a pre-EMPLOYMENT test and it came back *non-negative*.

What does this mean, is this the same as a positive result? Are there standard procedures I will have to take now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't analyze drug test reports, especially those we don't have access to, those we haven't read and those we shouldn't read because we don't have permission to read.

Comment: Did you take 3 home tests because you were hoping something was out of your system?

Answer (score 3):

The drug testing company doesn't fail you. They only report the scientific results. A Non-negative result is a test that shows some values above zero or at value that is above the noise.

Depending on the situation: any value above zero it is bad. Or it can be acceptable for the position or situation.

Situation:

- Ordered by the court to stay clean: non-negative can send you to jail
- Ordered by the court to get clean: non-negative could still be progress.
- Potential employer is federal government: non-negative could result in the loss of the job offer.
- Potential employer has no federal contracts: Non-negative can be acceptable.

The drug testing company doesn't decide what to do they just test the sample, and provide the results.

Comment: Or non-negative can be declared a false positive if and when compared to testing for the same drug took place in the home tests, assuming that testing for the same drug actually took place in the home tests. This is why I voted to  close the question - We don't have the test results and even if we had them, we don't have the expertise to evaluate them. Nor do we know anything about the OP's personal life to conclude that some medicine they took caused a false positive to be reported.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Drug Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_test) Wiki page

> if the test result of the immunoassay and GC-MS are **non-negative** and show a concentration level of parent drug or metabolite above the established limit, the MRO contacts the employee to determine if there is any legitimate reason—such as a medical treatment or prescription.

where MRO stands for medical review office.